# Find the limit of $a_n=\left(\frac{n-4}{n}\right)^{1-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I was trying to solve the following task and I even got the solution but I do not understand one step in the solution.

The task was to evaluate the limit of $$a_n=\left(\frac{n-4}{n}\right)^{1-n}$$

This is how far I got:

\begin{align}
a_n & =\left(\frac{n-4}{n}\right)^{1-n} \\
& = \left(1-\frac{4}{n}\right)^{1-n} \\
& = \left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)^{1-n} \\
& = \frac{\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)^n}\\
\end{align}

This, so far is equal to the solution but the solution just simply says the following:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)^n} =\frac{1}{e^{-4}}$$

I do know that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1\ +\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e$$
But how could I get to this? 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1\ +\frac{-4}{n}\right)^n = e^{-4}$$

Comment: Replace $$-\dfrac4n=\dfrac1m$$

Comment: How exactly does this help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place $\displaystyle\frac{-4}{n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{m}$ you obtain that $n = -4m$ so when $n \to \infty$ also $m \to \infty$. Hence: 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{m \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{-4m}=\lim_{m \to \infty}\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^{m}\right)^{-4}=e^{-4}$$

In general if you have $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n$ you could use the substitution $\displaystyle\frac{a}{n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{m}$ to obtain that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n = e^a$$

Answer (score 3):

It happens that, for each number $x$,$$\lim_n\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=e^x.$$

Comment: So, that's just a general thing that I should have known for that task?
When I saw the solution, I tried to extract the exponent somehow but it didnt work for me

Comment: @FinnEggers Yes, it's a general thing, although not hard to deduce. But I see that someone else has already shown you how to do it.

Comment: Yes. But thank you for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Note simply that

$$\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)^n = \left[\left(1+\frac{-4}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{-4}}\right]^{-4} \to e^{-4}$$

Indeed

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\left(1\ +\frac{1}{x}\right)^x = e$$